# Java & Android Calender to fetch all days by each month

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fetch days by each month.

```
    this.mCalander = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.mDf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
        mCalander.set(Calendar.YEAR, this.nextYear);
        for (int j = 0; j <= 11; j++) {
            mCalander.set(Calendar.MONTH, j);
            Log.d("INFO", "MONTH : " + (j + 1));

            int maxDay = mCalander.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            for (int k = 1; k <= maxDay; k++) {
                mCalander.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, k);
                Log.d("INFO", mDf.format(this.mCalander.getTime()));
            }
        }
    }
```

but the thing is it prints out incorrectly like

```
    2017-01-30
    2017-01-31
    MONTH : 2
    2017-03-01
    2017-03-02
```

as you see that

```
    Log.d("INFO", "Month : " +(j+1));
    for(k=0; k<maxDate; k++) {
       Log.d("INFO", mDf.format(this.mCalander.getTime()));
    }
```

could you tell me how to fix or reason why it happens like this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you trying to print all days month-wise of 2017?

Comment: @tahsinRupam yep that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendar gives you add() Method to increment/decrement value of any field in calendar, like add year, month, day etc. Check here : [Calendar.add(int, int)](http://file:///Volumes/DATA/Android-Setup/android-sdk-mac_86/docs/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int))

So you can also follow below approach, you can also loop for year range, I have set 2017 for demo.

```
mCalander.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
mCalander.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
int totalMonths = mCalander.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH);
for (int j = 0; j <= totalMonths; j++) {
    Log.d("INFO", "MONTH : " + j);
    int maxDay = mCalander.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mCalander.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    for (int k = 1; k <= maxDay; k++) {
        Log.d("INFO", k + " - " + mDf.format(mCalander.getTime()));
        mCalander.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.